# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'cycle'

Tags: jquery, primefaces, cycle

I use primefaces ImageSwitch to image slide show. And it works with no error. But I refrence jquery library to page, I get error same as title.

And I found a solution: I found this library :https://raw.github.com/malsup/cycle/master/jquery.cycle.all.js

I added this library to may page, And ImageSwitch is working now.

My question is Why? Why if I add Jquery , then I get this error? And Why if I add cycle library, then slideShow works again? Is there any another solution?

Any suggestion?

Thanks...

Comment: What does *...I refrence jquery library to page...* mean? Primefaces also uses the cycle plugin and of course jquery. When you add jquery to your page (again) you will end up having jquery twice and I guess your "referenced" jquery (which does not have access to the cycle plugin of primefaces) will get used somehow and fails because of this. Are you asking where exactly this fails?

Comment: @Jens, I want to know this. You mean, primefaces already have Jquery library, right? There is no need to add JQuery library to page as externaly?

Comment: Yes, primefaces already comes with jquery you do not have to add it again.

Comment: I edited the answer from @Joe to also include the info that primefaces already comes with jquery. You should accept his answer then. :)

Comment: Great behaviour :) you right...

Comment: Well, my EDIT of Joes question was rejected: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2185201 
So, maybe it wasn't so great. :-)
Anyways, it's in the comments that you do not need to put in jquery again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because it's trying to call `$('#element').cycle();` when you haven't included it on the page. If you're referring to this: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/imageSwitch.jsf then you can see that they're including a file called `imageswitch.js.jsf` which contains the jQuery Cycle Plugin.

`$.cycle()` isn't built into jQuery so an external library is required to enable this function.

Comment: No, there's no conflict. The function `.cycle()` just doesn't exist without the plugin. If you don't include the jQuery Cycle Plugin then you're calling a function that isn't available, hence the `Uncaught TypeError` message.

Comment: I mean if there is no jquery, then how jsf know cycle method?

Comment: It can't. On the primefaces page they're including this file: `http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces` which is the jQuery library. jQuery is required.

Comment: I m sorry, I m new for PF. So, I cant understand. If I dont add jquery, Can I use jquery methods? Because you say, PF is already refrence it

Comment: @Joe No, Primefaces already comes with jquery. If he adds the primeface jar to his project primefaces will automatically include jquery to the html pages.

Answer (score 1):

check for the "jquery.cycle" directory in 'sites\all\libraries\' folder. 
  if you dont have then create the directory in that folder as follow:

```
"libraries\jquery.cycle\"
```

and then add two jquery files in it:

```
jquery.cycle.all.js
jquery.cycle.all.min.js
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`cycle` is not a `jQuery` function. It is added by the `jQuery cycle plugin`. Hence regular `jQuery` does not know this method.